# Passing Variables between Widgets Pyside2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

I'm trying to figure out how to pass values between a list widget and a line edit widget using PySide2. I have a dictionary with three keys and a list with the same values as the three dictionary keys. When the user clicks on the value in the list box I want it to return the value from the dictionary key value pair. I'm able to retrieve the value from the dictionary if I manually enter the key in the code but I can't get it to accept the value from the list widget. Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QApplication, QMessageBox, QListWidget
from PySide2 import QtWidgets


item_dict = {1: "First Item",
            2: "Second Item",
            3: "Third Item"}

item_list = [1,2,3]

class myListWidget(QListWidget):
    def Clicked(self,item):
        click_id = self.item.text()

class myTextWidget(QLineEdit):
    def change_text(self):
        click_id = myListWidget.Clicked
        self.setText = item_dict[click_id]

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(window)
    listWidget = myListWidget()
    for i in item_dict:
       listWidget.addItem(str(i))

    TextWidget = myTextWidget()

    #listWidget.itemClicked.connect(listWidget.Clicked)
    listWidget.itemClicked.connect(myTextWidget.change_text)

    layout.addWidget(listWidget)
    layout.addWidget(TextWidget)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I click in the list widget I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mythranor\Desktop\VN Builder\PyQtTut\listview2.py", line 21, in change_text
    self.setText = item_dict[click_id]
KeyError: <function myListWidget.Clicked at 0x000002B6286A8F78>
```

I have also tried calling the listWidget.item.text directly within the change_text function but it says the listWidget variable is not recognized within the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has many inconsistencies, for example:

```py
def Clicked(self,item):
    click_id = self.item.text()
```

I presume that this method must return the text of the item but that function does not return anything, so even if it is invoked correctly you will always get None.

```
class myTextWidget(QLineEdit):
    def change_text(self):
        click_id = myListWidget.Clicked
        self.setText = item_dict[click_id]
```

You try to use myListWidget.Clicked but this will never work because to use a method you need an object besides that to invoke a function you must use parentheses and pass arguments if necessary.

From the above I presume that you do not have your knowledge of OOP entrenched, so it is recommended that you review your notes on that subject since Qt uses them intensively.

---

Therefore, the code will have to be rewritten. When you add items to the QListWidget you are converting to string and when you retrieve it it will also be a string so it cannot be used to access the associated value of the dictionary, so to avoid that conversion you can use the Qt::DisplayRole role directly so will show the numbers and the values will be retrieved as a number. On the other hand, never assume that everything works correctly but you have to verify, for example instead of using "[]" you can use "get()", in the first case if the key does not exist an exception will be thrown and in the Second, None or a default value will be returned. Considering the above, the solution is as follows:

```py
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

item_dict = {1: "First Item", 2: "Second Item", 3: "Third Item"}

item_list = [1, 2, 3]


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.listwidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.listwidget)
        lay.addWidget(self.lineedit)

        for e in item_list:
            it = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
            it.setData(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, e)
            self.listwidget.addItem(it)

        self.listwidget.itemClicked.connect(self.on_item_clicked)

    @QtCore.Slot(QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem)
    def on_item_clicked(self, item):
        key = item.data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
        value = item_dict.get(key)
        if value is not None:
            self.lineedit.setText(value)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Widget()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```